# "Added to review" label looks like a tag badge

Tags: support, revisions-list, timeline

When there is a question was closed and the author edited the post to reopen it, there is a new label added named "Added to review" in the revision and timeline of the post.

But the "Added to review" label looks like a tag badge. Initially, I thought it is a dupe hammer badge.

Is it purposely added like a badge? Or any design issue?

**Screenshots added for reference:**

**Revision history**: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/382521/revisions (for 10k+ reputation users)

[image: Revision history]

**Timeline**: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/382521/timeline (for 10k+ reputation users)

[image: Timeline]

Comment: To be fair, [a lot of other buttons and labels look like tag badges too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2UbY.png). There are only so many ways you can outline a rectangle. :-)

Comment: But having it have the same darker grey background and grey font colour as the 'history' labels to the left would already make more sense, I think, since it's a historical event.